# Use Python to open an Excel workbook

Tags: python, excel

I am learning Python through 'Automate the Boring Stuff With Python' First Edition. In chapter 12, pg 267, we are supposed to open a file called example.xlsx.

The author's code reads:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
type(wb)
```

However, when I try to open this file, I get the following error (this is the last line of the error):

> ```
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'example.xlsx'
> ```

I know this file exists, because I downloaded it myself and am looking at it right now.

I have tried moving it to the current location in which Python 3.8 is, I have tried saving it with my Automate the Boring Stuff files that I've been working on the desktop, and I have tried saving it in every conceivable location on my machine, but I continue getting this same message.

I have imported openpyxl without error, but when I enter the line

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
```

I have entered the entire pathway for the example.xlsx in the parenthesis, and I continue to get the same error.

What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to open an Excel workbook?

I still don't understand how I am doing wrong, but this one is incredibly infuriating, and I feel incredibly stupid, because it must be something simple.

Any insight/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try change your active directory or read from the full file path

Comment: You can use `os.getcwd()` to get current working directory. That is where python is looking for files with relative path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is *unambigous* — your file in a supposed directory *don't exist*. Believe me.

> For Python is irrelevant, whether **you** see it. **Python itself** must see it.

Specify the full path, using **forward** slashes, for example:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('C:/users/John/example.xlsx')
```

---

Or find out your **real** current (working) directory — and not the one *supposed by you* — with commands

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

then move your `example.xlsx` to it, and then use only the name of your file

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('example.xlsx')
```

---

You may also verify its existence with commands — use **copy/paste from your code** to avoid typos in the file name / path

```
import os.path
print(os.path.exists('example.xlsx'))                   # True, if Python sees it
```

or

```
import os.path
print(os.path.exists('C:/users/John/example.xlsx'))     # True, if exists
```

to be sure that I'm right, i.e. that the error *is not in the function `openpyxl.load_workbook()` itself,* but in its parameter (the path to the file) provided by **you**.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the extension of the example file is not the same as described in the book, is example.csv. I was facing the same frustration as you

Comment: Ok interesting. I think I ended up getting around this with some other advice on something I overlooked, but it's been a while since I've done anything in Python, so I will have to revisit this exercise and see if I understand what I am doing at all...